# Jpanel not showing up in safari

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I have an applet I have written that has a JLabel (containing an ImageIcon) and a custom ImagePanel inside a JPanel. For some reason the JLabel NEVER shows up in safari and firefox on mac os on first run/load but on other OSes (windows,linux) it appears fine. Now in the same applet there's a button that flips the image to another image. On safari/firefox on mac os, when the button is clicked, the second image shows, the when clicked again, the first image now appears!! Any idea what could be causing this issue? Even on safari for windows the applet works fine.. i.e. first image loads and appears.

UI code

```
    public void createUI(){
    mainpanel = new JPanel();
    mainpanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(154, 212));
    mainpanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(154, 212));
    mainpanel.setName("mainPanel");
    mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    lcdpanel = new ImagePanel(bgLcdImage);
    lcdpanel.setBounds(22, 22, 110, 28);

    bgImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bytes);//BufferedImage
    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bgImage));

    mainpanel.add(lcdpanel);
    mainpanel.add(label);
    mainpanel.invalidate();

    getContentPane().add(mainpanel);
    repaint();
    }
```

Button click code

```
    private void flipImage()
    {
      label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(backImg));
      label.repaint();
      lcdpanel.setVisible(false);
      lcdpanel.repaint();
      mainpanel.repaint();
      this.repaint();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When the applet loads do you want to show both `lcdPanel` and `JLabel` on screen? Note that `setBounds` will not work in your case because `Jpanel` is using default `FlowLayout` .. And `setBounds` works only when the layout of the container is set `null` although it is a bad practice ..

Comment: Yes I want both to be displayed and they both do on windows/linux but not on mac os browsers

Comment: Where do you want `JLabel` to be shown?

Comment: The jlabel is the "background" of the jpanel. The imagepanel is on top of the jlabel. The issue is not where i want the jlabel to be shown but WHY its not showing on Mac OS X firefox/safari browsers when it shows on windows/linux firefox/safari browsers.
I even made the jlabel as a imagepanel, set the layout of jpanel to null, called setbounds on both imagepanels and still got the same result. On windows/linux, both imagepanels appear after the applet loads/starts, on Mac OS X, only the lcdPanel appears, only after I flip the image and flip back will both images appear.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

> I even made the jlabel as a imagepanel, set the layout of jpanel to null

Setting the layout to null is the worst thing you can do. That will generally cause more problems than solve a problem.

> The issue is not where i want the jlabel to be shown but WHY its not showing on Mac OS X firefox/safari browsers when it shows on windows/linux firefox/safari browsers.

How do we know when only a few lines of code are posted? Post a proper `SSCCE` when you have a problem.

> On safari/firefox on mac os, when the button is clicked, the second image shows, the when clicked again, the first image now appears!!

The general format when adding/removing components on a visible GUI is to do:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

You never need to invoke repaint when you change the property of a component. Swing is smart enough to do the repaint for you.

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(backImg));
//label.repaint();
```